# How to order document .add() data in firestore in Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

Ive been struggling with ordering the documents in Cloud Firestore.
Im using the collection.add() method. And reading the data and displaying it on the screen.

Heres how i write it into the database:

```
let shared = {
                category : category,
                username : user.displayName,
                createdAt : date,
            }
            // Add a new document with a generated id.
            const sharedRef = db.collection('shared');
            sharedRef.orderBy('createdAt', "desc");
            sharedRef.add(shared)
                .then(function() {
                    console.log("Saved to database");
                }).catch(function(error) {
                console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
            });
```

[image]
And to Read the data I just use **doc.data forEach.**

I Read the data with **doc.data() forEach**

**Is there anyway i can order the shared documents by the date created?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`orderBy` is for queries that read data, not for adding data.  You can't set the order at the time you call `add()`.  The order you see in the console by default is always going to sort by the document ID, which is random for every call to `add()`.

You shouldn't be concerned about the order that the documents appear in the console.  You should only be concerned about putting fields in each document that you can use later to sort them in a query.

Comment: Thank you for the explication. 
Am I suppose to put the ** sharedRef.orderBy('createdAt', "desc");** where I am reading the data?

Comment: Yes, you use it to build a query as shown in the documentation.